# How can I set a WPF TreeView cells in this style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I am not sure what this style is called, but I guess you can call it stripped colors:

So basically one color for the first row, another color for the next row, and repeat.

Btw this image shows a ListView but I am trying to do it for a TreeView, so when you expand/collapse a node, it should still look correct.

I imagine this is more about styling the background than the cells themselves, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this style into your resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="AlternatingItems">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then, you declare your list view like this:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingItems}"
          AlternationCount="2"/>
```

See [this MSDN blog article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-alternating-rows) for more details.

Comment: Thanks man, it really works. Except I had to add quotes to TargetType and ItemContainerStyle. Is this correct? I will edit it and if it's wrong, please revert.

Comment: Actually just noticed a problem, when I expand a TreeView node, I still get the stripping but there are duplicates. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Joan: The same MSDN article discusses the treeview as well. (Perhaps you'll need to use some `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but I'm not familiar with that.)